# Make a stream out of a function call with RXJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, mobx

My problem is very simple, but I could'nt find an answer following different tutorial on RXJS.
I have a store in which I have a function that make a server call, this function is called right from my components, at startup time and later on as update are needed.
I want that function to be an Observable as fromEvent is used to observe keyBoard or Mouse Event from HTML Element.

how could I turn that function into a Stream returning a promise on each call.

```
this.getData(args) <Promise>
```

The thing is, I want my store to subscribe on that stream and update my Application State on each getData call, something that look like that.

```
this.getData.flatMap(promise => promise)
.subscribe(result => this.state.data = result)
```

Comment: Basically you want `.defer`?

Comment: no, defer seems to trigger the function ASA you subscribe to it, what I need is my stream to trigger result only when this.getData() is invoked, like fromEvent when you click or move your mouse, an event is triggered and you subscribe to it, I want that behavior when using this.getData(args)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I found what I was looking for, this can be handy to any silly beginner with RXJS

whenever you want to observe a call to a specific function, wrap it around Rx.observable.create like following

```
Rx.Observable.create(obs=>{
    this.getRestaurant = (variableString, variables, fragments) => {
      const query = this.getQuery(variableString, fragments)
      obs.onNext(graphQLFetcher({query: query, variables: variables}))
    }
  })
  .flatMap(promise => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise))
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result)
  });
```

now you have a nice stream based on this.getRestaurant(args) call.

Comment: I'm new in Rx, and I spend couple of hours to figure this out alone, but this unswer helped me a lot! Thanks!